# How to extract environment variable with boost::program_options?

Tags: c++, boost

Boost documentation does not provide a snippet of code with an example on how to parse environment variables. In contrast, it describes a strange behaviour of appending prefixes and converting to lowercases.
I tried to extract HOSTNAME environment variable but what I was able to do is to extract with this code PREFIX_HOSTNAME variable which I had to set manually.

```
  std::string hostname;
  boost::program_options::options_description desc_env;
  desc_env.add_options()("hostname", boost::program_options::value<string_type>(&hostname));

  boost::program_options::variables_map vm_env;
  boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::parse_environment(desc_env, "PREFIX_"), vm_env);
  boost::program_options::notify(vm_env);

  std::cout << "hostname: " << hostname << '\n'; // correct value of PREFIX_HOSTNAME environent variable
```

So, how to extract exactly HOSTNAME environment variable with boost::program_options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to extract environment variable without any names conversions, [this overload](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/parse_environ_idp682387952.html) of boost::program_options::parse_environment needs to be used.

The second argument here is a function that receives an existing environment variable and user shall respond which of a user-defined option he wants to populate with the value of this environment variable (empty string if none).

Here is the code:

```
std::string hostname;
boost::program_options::options_description desc_env;
desc_env.add_options()("hostname", boost::program_options::value<std::string>(&hostname));

boost::program_options::variables_map vm_env;
boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::parse_environment(desc_env, 
    [](const std::string& i_env_var)
    {// maps environment variable "HOSTNAME" to user-defined option "hostname"
         return i_env_var == "HOSTNAME" ? "hostname" : "";
    }),
    vm_env);
boost::program_options::notify(vm_env);

std::cout << "hostname: " << hostname << '\n'; // correct value of HOSTNAME environent variable
```